# Child onClick is ignored

Tags: reactjs

I have an component, that looked like this:

```
<ListItem onClick={() => history.push(`/link/${id}`)}>
    Sometext
    <Button onTouchTap={() => this.someFunction(false)} }
</ListItem>
```

The onTouchTab was provided by [react-tap-event-plugin](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin).

Since I read, that it [can now be replaced by onClick](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7129), I changed my code:

```
<ListItem onClick={() => history.push(`/link/${id}`)}>
    Sometext
    <Button onClick={() => this.someFunction(false)} }
</ListItem>
```

But now the issue is, that the button onClick is not recognized and only the onClick of the ListItem is taken.

How can I fix that?

Comment: are you stopping event propagation somewhere

Comment: the `onClick` will work on native elements. It's up to `<Button />` to implement onClick and bubble it via calling `props.onClick` - custom components don't get native events. eg `const Button = props => <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</button>`